Nginx configuration to create micro sites in a single domain website
I try to make Nginx working for micro site creation on a single domain website.
This is a WordPress website that has several Custom Post Types with specific sub directory URL.

example.com/cpt1/post_id
example.com/cpt2/post_id
example.com/cpt3/post_id

I want them to have below URL structure to visitors

cpt1.foo.com/article/post_id
cpt2.foo.com/article/post_id
cpt3.foo.com/article/post_id

and the main page of cpt_x.foo.com should example.com/cptx_main, which are individual pages.
Essentially, it is 1 page + 1 CPT (and I also have to map menus and categories, but those are less important)
I've tried with Nginx proxy_pass on foo.com as below.
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name cpt1.foo.com;

    location /article/ {
        rewrite ^/article/(.*)$ /cpt1/$1 break;  
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;  
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;  
        include /etc/nginx/global/proxy-pass-settings.conf;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /cpt1_main/$1 break;  # Rewrite the URL
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;  # Forward the request to the backend
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;  # Preserve the original host header
        include /etc/nginx/global/proxy-pass-settings.conf;
    }


where my proxy-pass-settings.conf is for proxy - backend setting
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
proxy_redirect off;

Up to above, it servers me well for each post/page in that visitors come to cpt_x.foo.com.
But, when they click on other posts while surfing around my website, they see the original url, which is

example.com/cpt_x/post_id

I want them to continue on cpt_x.foo.com/article/post_id.
I think I should do another step on the example.com's server block. If I set up redirection from /cpt_x/(.*)$ to cpt_x.foo.com/article/$1, I do have the url changed in the browser, but I end up with 404. I guess it is because the content is redirected. When I switch around minor details like regex, I get too many redirect.
I was going to set up something like alias, but I haven't been successful.
I also have tested with a number of WordPress plugins, but most of them do not support custom post types.
How can I solve this problem?
